# Linking Sprites to .txt file (P5JS/P5.PLAY)

Tags: javascript, text, sprite, p5.js

I am trying to make a game using p5js and p5.play. It is a top-down 2d racing game where the background is created by creating sprites and linking them to numbers from a .txt file called 'track.txt'.

I can't find anything online that even suggests what I should look at.

The numbers go as follow:

```
0 = Grass
1 = Track
2 = Finish/Start line

   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
   0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
   0 1 0 1 1 1 0 2 0
   0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
   0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
   0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
   0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
   0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: You could put the sprites in an array and use the number from the text file as index.

Comment: How would i go about doing this? Im new to coding and all the video i see dont talk about this type of problem

Comment: you don't ask a question here... what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Are you reading the text file's numbers into a two-dimensional array? The name for this technique is "tile engine", maybe that will help finding resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
let track = [];
let images = [];

function preload() {
  images[0] = loadImage("grass.png");
  images[1] = loadImage("track.png");
  images[2] = loadImage("finish.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  loadStrings("track.txt", getTrack);
}

function getTrack(arr){
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    let line = arr[i].trim();  //This is to make sure trailing spaces don't break the code
    let tempArr = line.split(" ");
    track.push(tempArr);
  }
}
```

You can then get the image like this:

```
function getImage(col, row) {
  return images[track[col][row]];
}
```